# How to hide the default options of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` to display contacts.

I also used `UISearchDisplayController` for searching of contacts.

I want to hide the options of `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` like Groups, All Contacts and cancel options

[image: Default Options image with search bar]

Is there any default properties to hide this.As I don't want these options in my app.

Please suggest any ideas. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you explain more about "hide the options of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController"?

Comment: Groups, All Contacts and cancel were the default options for Controller for ABPeoplePickerNavigationController. I want to hide those options..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController*)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
if([navigationController isKindOfClass:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class]]){
    navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    navigationController.topViewController.title = @"";
}
}
```

Comment: @nmh..Then SearchBar also hiding..along with options

Comment: @nmh.Thanks for answer.Its fine but cancel button is not hiding...using your code.